# Proving that the derivative at a local extremum is 0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

We wish to prove that for differentiable $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, if $f$ has a local extremum $c$, then $f'(c)=0$.

Proof:
Consider the function $f$ having a local maximum (otherwise consider $-f$).

Supposing $c$ is a local extremum, we must have that $f(c)\ge f(x)$ $\forall x \in(c-\delta,c+\delta), \delta>0$.

We know then that $f(x)-f(c)\le 0$. We also have that either $x-c <0$ or $x-c >0$, as we are assuming $x$ and $c$ are distinct.

Then, if we have $x-c>0$ then taking the limit as $x$ approaches $c$ of $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, we get that $f'(c) \le 0$.

On the other hand, if $x-c<0$ then taking the limit as $x$ approaches $c$ of $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, we get that $f'(c) \ge 0$.

For both conditions to hold, we must have $f'(c) =0$.

My lecturer gave a different proof in the notes for our module, but is this way correct?

Comment: Oh wow seriously? This way is much simpler than in the printed notes so I assumed it would be wrong.

Comment: Actually, the statement is false. It will become correct if you add that $c\in(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: You can also express your argument this way,  assuming only that one-sided derivatives exist.  (i) You first showed correctly that $f_+'(c)\leq 0$ for all $a\leq c < b$.  (ii) Then you showed in the same way  that $f_-'(c) \geq 0$ if $a< c \leq  b$.    Then you can conclude for $a<c<b$ that $f'(c)=0$ if it exists.  It is a bit more elegant if you have learned about one-sided derivatives.  You could even use the Dini derivatives.  Those of us who are lazy (i.e., all mathematicians) are tempted to prove (i) and declare that (ii) is "similar."